# PostBackOptions is not saves the form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-addin

The below code will redirect to the correct page. but the list is not saved.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
            button.removeAttr("onclick");
                button.click(function(event) {
                if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
                var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
                var aspForm = $("form#aspnetForm");
                var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
                var newPostbackUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
                if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
                WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true)) 
                return false;
            });
    });
```

suggest an idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the SharePoint version ? where I tried this before in 2013 ad not working ?!

Comment: I have tried it in Sharepoint 2013. @M.Qassas

Comment: Please Check my answer , that will match your requirements in SP 2013 , tell us the result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope It will work for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
// change redirection behavior
button.removeAttr("onclick");
button.click(function() {
var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
var aspForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.action;
var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
  var newPostbackUrl1 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue,newPostbackUrl1 );

if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following workaround

- Open `AllItems.aspx` page
- Edit Page > Add Script Editor
- Add this code

**[Code]**

```
 <script>   
 function RedirectAfterSave() {
    document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").removeAttribute("onclick"); 
    document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href="http://epm/workflow/Lists/Shoe%20Models/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://epm"; 

    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("RedirectAfterSave");
   </script>
```

**Note :**

At `document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href=` put your link to NewForm page before `Source Query String` and after it add your Custom Page URL that you want to go back.

Comment: It's not working @M.Qassas